# Technical advantages of either Configuration or Features over the other?

Tags: 7, features, configuration

In short, [Configuration](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) vs [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features), in Drupal 7, fight!

As always, *technical* advantages, or other hard facts, as we don't do *discussions* here. Drupal 7 specific to limit to scope, as CMI vs Features is a completely different discussion.

Comment: No contest - Configuration wins! But I have no facts to back that up, other than the fact I've been using it for a few months now and wouldn't even dream of going back to features. It's leaner, meaner, more easily extendable and generally a pleasure to work with

Comment: @Clive Which version are you using?  I've only looked at the project page, but is 1.x purely a '*featureless*' Features, with 2.x being more D8-ish?

Comment: @Chapabu, yes, I believe those two statements are correct. After a quick glance at 2.x, I'm having difficulties understanding how Config differs from "One really big monolithic feature"-Feature, hence my question. :)

Comment: @Chapabu I'm using 2.x, the biggest difference is the dependency injection and conformance to PSR-0 (which is the D8-ish bit). Apart from that they do pretty much the same thing

Comment: Looks pretty awesome :-)

Comment: I just read a technical fact right there! :) DI is a good thing, but it's not obvious to me how it plays a part here. Can you elaborate on that? :)

Comment: [Why configuration module over features module?](http://activelamp.com/blog/why-configuration-module-over-features-module) has a pretty good analogy for the non-technical (DI, PSR-0 etc) side of things.

Comment: Yeah, I read it, I find no sense at all in the baking analogy. Using Features doesn't mean that "flour is owned by birthday cakes".

Comment: @Letharion Thing is the DI/PSR-0 stuff isn't really a method for comparison between Config/Features, it's just how the codebase is laid out (i.e. 'namespaced' paths like `lib/Drupal/node/Plugin/Core/Entity/Node.php` for the node controller in D8). Don't get me wrong it's great that things are moving in this direction, but I wouldn't necessarily class that as an _advantage_ over Features as such. I'm afraid I haven't got anything tangible to say about the difference really, except that I always found Features 'clunky' and I don't get that feeling using Config :)

Comment: @Clive Do you tend to put *everything* under CM?  Or do you maintain a combination of Features and CM?  As far as I see, surely it's a case of checking almost every box in CM and then updating when needed?

Comment: Lots of comments... Not many answers... :)

Comment: @Chapabu I've stopped using Features altogether now, but then the sites I'm working on these days are highly customised and there's not enough overlap of functionality to justify using it. I've written a bunch of extension handlers for config (rules, commerce product/checkout pane, node limit, bundle inherit, etc) so now pretty much everything config-wise can live in code, which is absolutely ideal for me. I think the short answer to this question in general has already been touted - Config is Features without the Features...when you don't need the Features part of Features, use Config :)

Comment: It just makes the sad that "Config is Features without the Features" truly seems to have been the motivation for _forking_ the codebase, instead of improving the existing. I was hoping there would be other differences, but I guess the comments here sort of have the answer. I'll refrain from commenting more now, or this will get out of hand. :)

Comment: For stripped down features, have a look at: http://drupal.org/project/drush_ctex_bonus

Answer (score 2):

Watch Configuration for the future, because it more closely follows the model of Drupal 8. But I wouldn't suggest using it for now, because it is in alpha state, which means you need to be prepared to hack on it to keep it working, and you need to constantly update it, because it will not get formal Security Advisories if security issues are discovered.

Features is at 1.0, so it's a more stable choice for projects going to production soon, as you can trust that minor version updates will not break your existing features.